# Проверка наличия данных в словаре

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеются 3 словаря: `inventData`, `invent101` и `invent21`, которые я соединяю, делая из них 1 - `inventDataAll`.

Хотя словари и соединяются, но дело в том, что в словаре `inventData` есть данные которых нет в `invent101` и `invent21`. Мне необходимо, чтобы скрипт печатал, какие данные он не нашел, но это не происходит.

Вместо этого выводится "Инвентарник" + value['invent'] + "счетах не значится" именно столько раз сколько раз отрабатывает первый цикл, вне зависимости от того есть эти данные в `invent101` и `invent21` или нет.

Хотелось получить помощь по этому поводу.

```
inventData = {} # 1 словарь
# ...
inventData.setdefault(index, dict(name=name, serial=serial, invent=invent, produce=produce))
# ...
invent101 = {} # 2 словарь
# ...
invent101.setdefault(index, dict(invent=invent, checked=checked, worked=worked, cost=cost))
# ...
invent21 = {} # 3 словарь
# ... 
invent21.setdefault(index, dict(invent=invent, checked=checked, worked=worked, cost=cost))
# ...

inventDataAll = {} # Итоговый словарь
for key, value in inventData.items():
    for key101, value101 in invent101.items():
        if value['invent'] == value101['invent']:
            inventDataAll.setdefault(key,
                                     dict(name=value['name'], serial=value['serial'],
                                     invent=value['invent'],
                                     produce=value['produce'], checked=value101['checked'],
                                     worked=value101['worked'], cost=value101['cost']))
        elif value['invent'] != value101['invent']:
            for key21, value21 in invent21.items():
                if value['invent'] == value21['invent']:
                    inventDataAll.setdefault(key,
                                             dict(name=value['name'], serial=value['serial'],
                                             invent=value['invent'],
                                             produce=value['produce'], checked=value21['checked'],
                                             worked=value21['worked'], cost=value21['cost']))
    else:
         print("Инвентарник" + value['invent'] + "счетах не значится")
```

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, else должно быть на одном уровне с if, а сейчас оно на одном уровне со внутреннем for, поэтому код в этом else срабатывает каждый раз, когда успешно завершается внутренний for.

Comment: Покажите структуру словарей. Возможно, есть более изящный способ найти расхождения.

Comment: Уважаемый @Sergey Gornostaev на счет структуры словарей, данные берутся из 3-х екселевских файлов, долго думал как объединить данные, додумался только до этого.

Comment: По поводу комментария товарища @insolor esle переставлял не раз во всевозможных вариациях, баловался с brake, ничего путного не выходит. я понял о чем Вы, но мне кажется все что можно я перепробовал

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev структуру указал выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вместо этого выводится "Инвентарник" + value['invent'] + "счетах не значится" именно столько раз сколько раз отрабатывает первый цикл, вне зависимости от того есть эти данные в invent101 и invent21 или нет.

`else` у вас относится к вложенному `for`. В этом случае `else` вызывается, если `break` внутри `for` не вызван. Намерение, чтобы вместо:

```
found = False
for hay_or_needle in haystack:
    if hay_or_needle == needle:
        found = True
        break
if not found:
    print("no needle in the haystack")
```

писать просто:

```
for hay_or_needle in haystack:
    if hay_or_needle == needle:
        break # found
else:
    print("no needle in the haystack")
```

Обратите внимание: `else` под `for` находится, а не под `if`.

Я не вижу `break` во вложенном цикле, поэтому код из `else` выполняется при каждом проходе во внешнем цикле.

---

Что у вас код делает, тяжело понять. Минимальное изменение: уберите `else` в конце и используйте: `if key not in inventDataAll` вместо этого.

Вы можете вынести повторяющийся код в функцию (не тестировано):

```
from operator import itemgetter

def dict_subset(mapping, keys):
    return dict(zip(keys, itemgetter(*keys)(mapping)))

# merge (values from invent101 overwrite invent21)
inv = {v['invent']: v for d in [invent21, invent101] for v in d.values()} 

inventDataAll = {}
for key, value in inventData.items():
    if value['invent'] in inv:
        inventDataAll[key] = {
            **dict_subset(value, 'name serial invent produce'.split()),
            **dict_subset(inv[value['invent']], 'checked worked cost'.split())}
    else:
        print("Инвентарник {[invent]} счетах не значится".format(value))
```

Посмотрите, не будет ли это яснее выглядеть в виде SQL (можно `db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')` попробовать).